# how to store 1D vector<point2f> in Mat and how to access those points in Mat?

Tags: opencv, vector, mat

I have a 1D vector of point2f. I am storing those points in 2D Mat of size 6x6. How to access these points now?

Comment: Which language are you using? Can you also attach sample code snippet as well ?

Comment: what's the type of the mat elements? Why 6x6 Mat? Doesn't it depend on the number of points (the size of the vector)?

Comment: @ZdaR I am using VS open CV 3.2, C++. I will attach the code now.

Comment: @Micka Type of Mat is float. 6x6 is my requirement. And yes it also depends on the size of vector. I will attach the code snippet for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help:)  I sorted the answer now.

```
vector<Point2f>centers(36); //I have 1D vector of points which is of size 36
Mat new_mat = Mat(centers).reshape(6, 6); //1d vector to 6x6matrix

**/*Actually the Point2f, when stored in Mat makes use of the channels for storing the float values*/**

Mat test = new_mat.reshape(2, 6);// this makes 6 channels into two rows

**/*My objective here is to transpose the vector  which is now stored in Mat*/**

Mat q1 = test.t();//transposed 6 channel mat

vector<Point2f>x(q1.begin<Point2f>(), q1.end<Point2f>());//transposed vector
```

Now we can access the Point2f stored in Mat, by test.at(0,1) or accordingly.

**Summary:**
vectorx -> Mat (2D) size 6x6 -> reshape-> do req changes or modification in the Mat ->Converted again to vectorx_output